# Magento 2 Plugin implementation for js frontend?

Tags: magento2, javascript, frontend, plugin

A plugin as far as I read is created for intercepting a **PHP** function call and running code before, after, or around that function call. Is there a way how to accomplish that in js file?

**How can i intercept Magento 2 module js file function call with another function that is located in another module?**

**Example:** js generates an array and i want to add additional element into that array with another module, before it gets processed by another js function. Similar to what is done in magento checkout customization tutorials but only using js file(s) (adding layout elements dynamically).

PS: Can it be done and if not then why? What might be cons? Sorry if that is against any js patterns or best practices?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You do this with using a requirejs `mixin` and the `mage/utils/wrapper` js module.

Heres a demonstration of how the `wrapper` module functions:

```
var wrapper = require('mage/utils/wrapper');

function multiply(a, b) {
    return a * b;
}

var wrapped1 = wrapper.wrap(multiply, function (_super) {
    var result = _super();
    return result + 1;
});

var wrapped2 = wrapper.wrap(multiply, function (_super, a, b) {
    a += 1;
    return _super(a, b);
});

multiply(2, 2); // result is 4
wrapped1(2, 2); // result is 5
wrapped2(2, 2); // result is 6
```

In this example, `wrapped1` works like an 'after' plugin, and `wrapped2` works like a 'before' plugin. You can combine the two to get an 'around' plugin.

For a real world example, here's how to create a plugin for the `collectData` method of `Magento/Ui/view/base/web/js/form/from.js`. We need to use a requirejs 'mixin' to do this.

In your module, create the file `Your/Module/view/base/web/requirejs-config.js`:

```
var config = {
    'config': {
        'mixins': {
            'Magento_Ui/js/form/form': {
                'Your_Module/js/plugin': true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Now make the file `Your/Module/view/base/web/js/plugin.js`:

```
define([
    'mage/utils/wrapper'
], function (wrapper) {
    'use strict';

    return function (Form) {

        var newMethod = wrapper.wrap(Form.collectData, function (_super, items) {
            items = before(items); // the 'before' plugin
            var result = _super(items); // call original method
            return after(result); // the 'after' plugin
        });

        Form.collectData = newMethod; // replace original method with wrapped version

        return Form;
    }
});
```

You can read more about `mixins` and `wrapper` here: http://alanstorm.com/the-curious-case-of-magento-2-mixins/

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me. The only way I can get the mixin to intercept the original method is using Form.extend({... otherwise it simply ignores everything else using the logic provided above.

Comment: You're correct, since Form is a uiClass constructor, we should extend it. The above method should be used for modules that export an object.

Comment: We can use wrapper.wrapSuper to extend a js object, refer: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/javascript-dev-guide/javascript/js_mixins.html