# Magento 2 javascript plugin after method is executed in wrong time

Tags: magento2, javascript, plugin, mixins

Following [this post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/158072/27598) answer I have used mixins of [`shipping.js`](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.1/app/code/Magento/Checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/shipping.js) file to change the result of `validateShippingInformation` method. My `requirers-config.js` file is:

```
var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'Magento_Checkout/js/view/shipping': {
                'Vendor_checkoutShipping/js/shipping-method-mixin': true
            }
        }
    }};
```

and `shipping-method-mixin.js` file:

```
define([
'jquery',
'mage/utils/wrapper',], function ($, wrapper) {
'use strict';

return function (shipping) {

    var newMethod = wrapper.wrap(shipping.validateShippingInformation, function (originalFunction) {
        var result = originalFunction();
        return after(result);
    });
    console.log(newMethod);
    shipping.validateShippingInformation = newMethod; 

    return shipping;
};});
```

**Problem I have:** The file is read by browser when page is loaded (identified by breakpoints) and right then executed. But the method in original file that i tray to extend by using after method is executed by button click in front-end (why is the file not running `after` the original method is executed). I do not need the script I added to run when the page is loading(reloaded) and I do not want to override the original javaScript file.

**I need to change `validateShippingInformation` value *before* the method `setShippingInformation` `if` sentence is being executed.** The if sentence in shipping.js file is:

```
if (this.validateShippingInformation()) {.(I need to allow or disallow this code to run based on my additional logic. How can i do it?).}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you look at target file `Magento/Checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/shipping.js`,you'll see that this is `requirejs` module which returns UiComponent (child of `Magento_Ui/js/form/form`).

In your example you have been used `mage/utils/wrapper` but this `util` applicable only for functions (like `Magento/Checkout/view/frontend/web/js/action/create-billing-address.js`).

For extending UiComponent you need to use base method `extend`:

```
var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'Magento_Checkout/js/view/shipping': {
                'Vendor_checkoutShipping/js/shipping-method-mixin': true
            }
        }
    }};
```

`shipping-method-mixin.js`

```
define([], function () {
    'use strict';

    return function (Component) {
        return Component.extend({
            validateShippingInformation: function () {
                var result = this._super();
                result = this._modifyResult(result);

                return result;
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Your answer was very helpful, but I thing that the answer would be more helpful to others and more complete if you replace this row `return alert('validate') && this._super();` with a way to change the original method (after). I have had doubts to accept your answer because @David Verholen showed in his answer showed how can I do that

Comment: sure, i did it!

Answer (score 5):

I'm not 100% sure, but I think mixins on ui components do not work as you are expecting it, since ui components return an ui component object which work slightly differtent, like further described [here](http://alanstorm.com/the-curious-case-of-magento-2-mixins/).

what you can do, is overriding the ui component (by creating the file in your theme like: `app/design/Vendor/theme/Magento_Checkout/web/js/view/shipping.js`) in your theme and extend it from the original ui component:

```
/*global define*/
define(['Magento_Checkout/js/view/shipping'], function (Component) {
        'use strict';
        return Component.extend({
            validateShippingInformation: function () {
                var originalResult = this._super();
                var newResult = this.doYourStuff(originalResult);
                return newResult;
            }
        });
    }
);
```

while you can of course add any object you need to the define function array

Comment: nope, mixins are applied for any requirejs modules, which return any value (component, function, object, text).

Comment: I agree while basically you are doing exactly the same using another  overriding mechanism